# Difference between the way object values are fetched in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, visualforce-component

In salesforce any object attribute value(let say case recordtypeid), can be fetched using two ways,

`{!$case.RecordTypeid}` - with dollar sign

`{!Case.RecordTypeid}` - without dollar sign

Can anybody help what the difference between both and also which one to use when?

Answer (score 3):

Generally one is a global variable and another is a merge field.

- The global variable `{!$Label.MyLabel__c }` is a kind of merge field that is *a built in feature* of salesforce
- A normal merge field `{!Account.Name}` *can be defined by user* (apex controller,
  standard controller, ...)

---

The `!` sign followed by `$` is a [Global Variable](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm).

> Use global variables to reference general information about the
>   current user and your organization on a page.

That means that you can access *some* information from *some* objects on the visualforce page or in a apex code *directly* without having to query a database ([check out a list with all global variables here](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_variables_global.htm)). Additionally read this useful topic for better understanding what a gloab variable is: ["Understanding Global Variables"](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_understanding_global_variables.htm&siteLang=en_us)

---

The `!` sign alone (without `$`) is a [Merge Field](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=pages_merge_fields.htm&language=en_US).

For example if your vialforce page use a standard account controller, you can access fields from that object directly using this syntax: `{!Account.Name}`

Or you can define some variable in APEX controller and reference it on the viasualforce page using this syntax too.